# How to always show a top li in typeahead with angular ui bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to use typeahead in ui bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to add a drop down for existing options.  I want the user to always have the option of selecting a li that says "+ add new" (see example code).

Do you know how I could add a li that is always on the top of the li list?

**What I am trying to display in the dropdown:**

```
<input value="">
<ul>
  <li>+ Add New</li>
  <li>Boots</li>
  <li>Shoes</li>
  <li>Hats</li>
</ul>
```

**the angular html and directive**

```
<div class="row form-group" ng-app="filterSelect">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <label for="">State:</label>
      <div class="btn-group s-search-filter">
        <span class="s-search-input" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
          <input type="text" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Search" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script charset="utf-8">
  angular.module('filterSelect', ['ui.bootstrap']);
  function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.selected = undefined;
    $scope.states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by implementing a custom filter in angularjs.

```
autocompleteApp.filter('statesFilter', function() {
    return function(states, searchText) {
        var filtered = ['+ Add New'];
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(states, function(state) {
            if (state.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText) != -1)
                filtered.push(state);
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

here's the html

```
<input type="text" 
 ng-model="selected" 
 placeholder="Search" 
 typeahead="state for state in states | statesFilter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" 
 class="form-control">
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as i know you can not do it.
Once a had the similar problem: i had to show my input text before all results. So, i wrote my own directive over `typeahead` directive. Unfortinally, i didn't finish that one, but you can try to modify that one.

The main idea is that before showing results you process you `Array` jf results and `unshift()` your own value. You could modify that one and insert some special value for `add new` value.

Also, these directive works only with `Arrays of Objects`.

#### Here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/DKi5ONvNFtXPonwOHqtX?p=info

Hope, it will be usefull for you.